# ASP.net MVC - Pass list to View as a Tuple member

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass Tuple with 4 members to View.

Controller:

```
   PGOrders pGOrder = db.PGOrders.Find(id);
   int imgID = pGOrder.imageID;
   PGOrderImages pGorderImages = db.PGOrderImages.Find(imgID);
   PGAccountDatas account = db.PGAccountDatas.Where(a => a.PGAccountDataID == pGOrder.ordererID).FirstOrDefault();
   var  offs = db.PGOffers.Where(o => o.orderID == pGOrder.PGOrderID);

return View(Tuple.Create(pGOrder, pGorderImages, account, offs));
```

View:

```
@using projectname.Models
@model Tuple<PGOrders, PGOrderImages, PGAccountDatas, IQueryable<PGOffers>>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Item4){
            <text><p> some item property</p></text>
        }
```

The problem is in line with foreach loop.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
```

I tried to change 
`var  offs = db.PGOffers.Where(o => o.orderID == pGOrder.PGOrderID);`
to 
`var  offs = db.PGOffers.Where(o => o.orderID == pGOrder.PGOrderID).ToList();`

and in View change 
`IQueryable<PGOffers>` for `IEnumerable<PGOffers>` 
but its didnt help.

pGOrder, pGorderImages, account are a specified class objects.

The Question is:

**How to pass List of class objects as a member of Tuple?**

Comment: You didn't include the relevant information.  What is offs?  What is PGOffers a collection of?   Why are singular items plural in your model (A singular PGOffers would be a PGOffer, not PGOffers).

Comment: I highly recommend that you create a view model with the attributes you want, populate it in the controller and then pass it to the view.  This methodology will be much more maintainable over the long run.

Comment: why don't you avoid this tuple madness, create a model class to hold all the data you need and then work with that? Simple is always better isn't it? Oh and avoid IQueryable in your model, that's not data.

Comment: Tuples? WTF? You are probably looking for view models. Now that I am giving it a second thought: not *probably*, but you are *definitely* looking for view models.

Comment: What happens when you call ToList and use IEnumerable in the View. Same Exception? Where?

Comment: @RobertMcKee PGOffers and PGOrders are POCO classes created accordingly to database tables - nothing special, ints and strings only.

Comment: nurdyguy,   AndreiDragotoniu,  Darin Dimitrov  I have use view model in other controller in this project. I am actually learning about asp.net and I want to try different ways to passing data.

Comment: @IvayloStoev when I changed as You suggested its appear the same exception `Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.` in line: `var  offs = db.PGOffers.Where(o => o.orderID == pGOrder.PGOrderID).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

you must convert to enumerable, like below:

```
var  offs = db.PGOffers.Where(o => o.orderID == pGOrder.PGOrderID).AsEnumerable();
```

then set your model to :

```
@model Tuple<PGOrders, PGOrderImages, PGAccountDatas, IEnumerable<PGOffers>>
```

Comment: I changed it, but on line :

            `@foreach (var item in Model.Item4)
           `
still error appear:
`Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.`